# Can Ask Different Blog administrators add custom CSS?

Tags: support, blog

There are times when it would be very useful to be able to use custom CSS for a blog post.

Under the blog's Dashboard-> Appearance-> Stack Exchange Options, I see a `CSS Folder` option. Does that mean that the administrators can add CSS?

If so, how can we access that folder?
If not, is there a way we can work things out so that this is possible?

Some use cases for this:

- We want to add some global styling that isn't part of the theme (think podcast player, App Store links, etc.)
- We want to do a one-off thing for a particular post that's more complex than the theme offers (think two side-by-side images, some huge text, or something colorful).
- We need to put a quick bug fix or patch in place so that we can get a post out (this would just be temporary until SE can deploy a fix).

**Update:**

I've tested and found that I can include some inline styles (`<span style="color: green;">hello world</span>` works).
But, it appears that this styling is subject to a whitelist (`overflow-x: scroll;` is stripped).
Inline styles, of course, also don't allow us to make our own classes to reuse (think stuff we do a lot, like podcast guests' photos, a potential inline audio player, etc).

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not a means for this to be done via the ui.  That option is part of our custom theme, but it isn't for enabling css to be changed by admins.

I'm not seeing a need to open this up.  I'd want to see a compelling case calling for it.

Comment: I've added a few use cases. This is just a 'first ideas' thing; I'll add more as I think of them. Thanks.